# How to integrate alfresco with ofbiz

Tags: alfresco, ofbiz

Could anyone let me know how can we integrate alfresco with ofbiz?

Answer (score 4):

I never used ofbiz, but I did integrate Alfresco with a lot of different systems. If you can integrate at the HTTP level and you only need to share content between the apps, you have a number of choices here to pull and push content to Alfresco straight away:

- [CMIS](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS)
- [Web Scripts](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts)
- [SOAP Web Services](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Content_Management_Web_Services)

Web Scripts also provide rendering, which helps in creating some custom UI controls to be pulled from ofbiz.

EDIT: just to be clear, all the protocols above are meant to be consumed from the outside, i.e. with a passive Alfresco instance that reacts to HTTP calls from ofbiz

Hope this helps!